# No hyperlink for server name part of multi email text

Tags: spacing, hyperref, links

I am trying to have something like `{name1, name2}@server.com` where `name1` and `name2` have hyperlinks of `name1@server.com` and `name2@server.com`. This is my code:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\{\href{mailto:name1@server.com}{name1}
\href{mailto:name2@server.com}{name2}\}@server.com
```

but in the out put, `}@server.com` has also a link which is `}@server.com`. The only solution I found for this is to have a space between `}` and `@` which I don't like it. Is there anyway to disable the hyperlink for `@` so that the output would be `{name1, name2}@server.com` where `name1` and `name2` have hyperlinks of `name1@server.com` and `name2@server.com`?

Comment: I think, this comes from your pdf-viewer which automatically recognizes potential hyperlinks. I actually don't know how to come by, maybe you can somehow exchange the dot with something else, so your pdf-viewer can't recognize it anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the heuristics of the PDF viewer, that turns "}@server.com" into a link. At least with AR9/Linux, the heuristics is defeated, if the dot comes from a different font, e.g. a math font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\{\href{mailto:name1@server.com}{name1},
\href{mailto:name2@server.com}{name2}\}@server$.$com
\end{document}
```

### Different method using an invisible explicit space character

The next example inserts an explicit space character after `@` to fool the heuristics to see `}@ server.com` instead of `}@server.com`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newfont{\spacefont}{phvr8r}
\newcommand*{\dummyspace}{%
  \leavevmode
  \rlap{\spacefont\symbol{32}}%
}

\begin{document}
\{\href{mailto:name1@server.com}{name1},
\href{mailto:name2@server.com}{name2}\}@\dummyspace server.com
\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- An explicit space character is a little tricky, because TeX usually replaces the space with horizontal skip space. Therefore I have used a different font that does have a space character at position 32 (space).

(In a pre-release version of pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 for TeX Live 2014 it triggered a bug, see [bug report on pdfTeX mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2014-May/008900.html). The bug is now (2014-05-23) fixed.)

Comment: Thanks @Heiko, but the first solution doesn't work!

Comment: @M0HS3N: It depends on the heuristics of the used PDF viewer and even the version of the PDF viewer.

Comment: @ Heiko Oberdiek: I tried your second solution and it works. Thank you.