# Manually remove hyperlink / link

Tags: hyperref

How do I manually remove a hyperlink so it does not become clickable ? For example, in the moderncv entry of

```
\email{test@hotmail.com}
```

Comment: Omit the `\email` wrapper and just write `test@hotmail.com`?

Comment: @Mico: Much too easy. `\renewcommand{\email}[1]{#1}`.... I am sure, egreg will provide an `expl3` solution for this and David has `\def\zzzemail#1{#1}`...

Comment: Related: [No hyperlink for server name part of multi email text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179574/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\email` is just a macro that stores the email address in the macro `\@email`:

> ```
> % defines one's email (optional)
> % usage: \email{<email adress>}
> \newcommand*{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}}
> ```

Macro `\emaillink` is actually the macro that generates the link:

> ```
> % makes an email hyperlink
> % usage: \emaillink[optional text]{link}
> \newcommand*{\emaillink}[2][]{%
>   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
>     {\href{mailto:#2}{#2}}%
>     {\href{mailto:#2}{#1}}}
> ```

It can be redefined to strip off the `\href` stuff:

```
\renewcommand*{\emaillink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{#2}{#1}%
}
```

Comment: This may still result in a clickable link since the PDF parser can interpret an @<server> text as an email. However, this is viewer-dependent.